# Running batch script remote

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to run a batch script remotely

```
python C:\FtpServer.py
```

when i start it manually it works fine, but when i use the remote script the python process wont start or terminates directly.

my python code is

```
import wmi
import win32con
connection = wmi.WMI("10.60.2.244", user="XY", password="XY")
startup = connection.Win32_ProcessStartup.new(ShowWindow=win32con.SW_SHOWNORMAL)
process_id, return_value = connection.Win32_Process.Create(CommandLine="C:\\startFtpServer.bat", ProcessStartupInformation=startup)
```

I get a pid and return value is 0

When i tasklist in cmd on the remote machine the process is not listed. Just starting python.exe instead of that batch file with that script works fine though.

Comment: As soon as i posted this i recognized i tricked myself by looking on the wrong Process ID (that one from commando shell), is it possible to find out the Process ID of the started python process? Maybe multiple python.exe are running... need to find out the one i just started. Can i start the process with wmi module interacting with user session so i see the commando shell window on remote machine?